# Writing SQL query with logic given

Tags: sql-server

I need to create flag (y) where sell_date equal to ord_dt or ord_dt is between 0-4 days before sell_date or ord_dt is 1 day after sell_date, rest flagged as N.

See the sample data and result expected:

```
create table #data (id int, ord_dt date, sell_dt date)

insert into #data values(101, '2020-05-16','2020-05-15')
insert into #data values ( 102,'2020-05-16','2020-05-15')
insert into #data values ( 103,'2020-05-16','2020-05-15')
insert into #data values ( 103,'2020-05-20','2020-05-15')
insert into #data values ( 104,'2020-05-13','2020-05-13')
insert into #data values ( 104,'2020-05-17','2020-05-14')
insert into #data values ( 104,'2020-05-21','2020-05-14')
insert into #data values ( 105,'2020-05-15','2020-05-15')
insert into #data values ( 105,'2020-05-19','2020-05-15')
insert into #data values ( 106,'2020-05-19','2020-04-19')
insert into #data values ( 107,'2020-04-13','2020-04-13')
insert into #data values ( 107,'2020-05-15','2020-05-15')
insert into #data values ( 107,'2020-05-19','2020-05-15')
insert into #data values ( 108,'2020-05-20','2020-05-19')

create table #data_result_result (id int, ord_dt date, sell_dt date, flag varchar)

insert into #data_result values(101, '2020-05-16','2020-05-15', 'Y')
insert into #data_result values ( 102,'2020-05-16','2020-05-15','Y')
insert into #data_result values ( 103,'2020-05-16','2020-05-15','Y')
insert into #data_result values ( 103,'2020-05-20','2020-05-15','N')
insert into #data_result values ( 104,'2020-05-13','2020-05-13','Y')
insert into #data_result values ( 104,'2020-05-17','2020-05-14','Y')
insert into #data_result values ( 104,'2020-05-21','2020-05-14','N')
insert into #data_result values ( 105,'2020-05-15','2020-05-15','Y')
insert into #data_result values ( 105,'2020-05-19','2020-05-15','N')
insert into #data_result values ( 106,'2020-05-19','2020-04-19','Y')
insert into #data_result values ( 107,'2020-04-13','2020-04-13','Y')
insert into #data_result values ( 107,'2020-05-15','2020-05-15','Y')
insert into #data_result values ( 107,'2020-05-19','2020-05-15','N')
insert into #data_result values ( 108,'2020-05-20','2020-05-19','Y')
```

Comment: The requirement as you described it is different than your expected results.

Comment: Can you explain why for the row: 104,'2020-05-17','2020-05-14' you want 'Y'?

Comment: Also for 106,'2020-05-19','2020-04-19' why 'Y' (the difference is 1 month)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
CREATE TABLE #data_result ( id INT, ord_dt DATE, sell_dt DATE, flag VARCHAR );
INSERT INTO #data_result
SELECT id
    , ord_dt
    , sell_dt
    , Iif(sell_dt = ord_dt
          OR DateDiff(DAY, ord_dt, sell_dt) = 4
          OR DateDiff(DAY, sell_dt, ord_dt) = 1, 'Y', 'N')
FROM #data;
SELECT * FROM #data_result;
```

As you can see, the IIF operator is nice to have in scenarios like this. The first argument to IIF is a Boolean expression that evaluates to True or False. Depending on this the second or third parameter is returned.

The DateDiff method is useful for calculating differences between dates.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you need a `CASE` expression that uses the function [`datediff()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to calculate the difference of the 2 dates in days:

```
select *,
  case 
    when datediff(day, ord_dt, sell_dt) between -1 and 4 then 'Y'
    else 'N'
  end flag 
from #data
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a817d815581ae5acab96518117fedea8).
Results:

```
>  id | ord_dt     | sell_dt    | flag
> --: | :--------- | :--------- | :---
> 101 | 2020-05-16 | 2020-05-15 | Y   
> 102 | 2020-05-16 | 2020-05-15 | Y   
> 103 | 2020-05-16 | 2020-05-15 | Y   
> 103 | 2020-05-20 | 2020-05-15 | N   
> 104 | 2020-05-13 | 2020-05-13 | Y   
> 104 | 2020-05-17 | 2020-05-14 | N   -- ord_dt is 3 days after sell_dt so 'N'  
> 104 | 2020-05-21 | 2020-05-14 | N   
> 105 | 2020-05-15 | 2020-05-15 | Y   
> 105 | 2020-05-19 | 2020-05-15 | N   
> 106 | 2020-05-19 | 2020-04-19 | N   -- the difference is 1 month so 'N'
> 107 | 2020-04-13 | 2020-04-13 | Y   
> 107 | 2020-05-15 | 2020-05-15 | Y   
> 107 | 2020-05-19 | 2020-05-15 | N   
> 108 | 2020-05-20 | 2020-05-19 | Y
```